# returning for loops in functions in python

Tags: function, loops

How do I return the entire list of numbers from my loop in this function?

```
def ChickenMonster(message):
    for i in message:
       num = ord(i)
       if num >= 97 and num<=122:
          num = num - 97
       if num >= 65 and num <=90:
          num = num - 65
       if num < 65 or num >  122:
          continue 
    return num
print ChickenMonster("ABC")
```

It only returns the value for "C" which is 2, and I want it to display 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 0):

Your *num* variable is only the last element in the string, you need to create an array and then add to it, returning the array.

```
def ChickenMonster(message):
    return_array = []
    for i in message:
       num = ord(i)
       if num >= 97 and num<=122:
          num = num - 97
       if num >= 65 and num <=90:
          num = num - 65
       if num < 65 or num >  122:
          continue
       return_array.append(num)
    return return_array
print ChickenMonster("ABC")
```